# VirtualBox CentOS 7 installation- why just command line, no desktop?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos-7

In one of my previous jobs, I used a number of Virtual Machines as part of the development process for our software (CentOS 5, CentOS 7 & Windows XP). The VMs were mainly used for hosting the back-end of my development environment, so that I could develop the front-end locally. These VMs were installed & set up by a colleague prior to my starting there, so I was not involved in their installation/ set up at all.

I recently started a new position with another company, and find myself needing to use a VM again for similar development purposes. Given that I have used CentOS 7 before, I decided to try using that again, so I have downloaded VirtualBox, and downloaded a CentOS 7 .iso image.

I ran through the installation guide [here](http://www.jeramysingleton.com/install-centos-7-minimal-in-virtualbox/), and while this appears to have installed successfully, when I start the CentOS 7 VM, it only opens a terminal- asks me to log in, and then I can see that I am at the root location of the VM.

When previously working with CentOS 7, there was a whole GUI (virtual PC desktop)- why is it that this doesn't appear to have been installed with the CentOS 7 VM that I have installed? Is there a way to 'add' this to the installation, or will I need to try another VM to have the 'desktop' feature, rather than just the command line?

Comment: You installed CentOS minimal. This comes with no desktop environment by default. When installing choose something like Server with GUI, or GNOME Desktop, or KDE Plasma Workspace during the Base Environment part of the install if you want a full desktop environment.

Comment: You could install a desktop environment of your choice on top of what you have now, but if it's not something you've ever done before you're probably just better off scrapping that VM and start from scratch with a new install. You'll save yourself time and hassle that way.

Comment: Thanks- I did wonder which option to choose when going through the setup, but wasn't aware that was what I'd need. Reinstalled and selected the GNOME desktop- it's all working as I expected.

Comment: @n8te If you want to post that comment as an answer, I'll mark it accepted. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the instructions you followed in the [link](http://www.jeramysingleton.com/install-centos-7-minimal-in-virtualbox/) you provided, it looks like you installed the **CentOS minimal version**. This is a bare bones installation that comes with no GUI/desktop environment by default.

Although you could still install a desktop environment on top of what you have now, the fact that this is a newly installed VM you just created it'll be quicker and easier to scrap it and start the install all over.

During the **Software Selectio**n part of the installation, under **Base Environment**:

- **Server with GUI**
- **GNOME Desktop Environment**
- **KDE Plasma Workspace**
- **Development and Creative Workstation**

.......would all be possible options you could select for a GUI environment.